# Diminished volition

Tags: five-skandas

This article titled [The Theory of Kama](http://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/karma.htm) says,

> Volition, or Will (*tetana*), is itself the doer, Feeling (*vedana*) is
>   itself the reaper of the fruits of actions.

So feelings are the fruit of will and of actions.

Is the the converse also true: does diminished volition and not-acting create karma that will have a neutral sensation?

Comment: i'm thinking of dreams tbh, but the question seemed of general interest

Comment: Can someone explain the down vote on this?

Answer (score 1):

The sensations are decided by the motivation of volition behind "non action" which on its own is an action.

Diminished volition can occur in a Vipassana partitioner who is seeing sensations arising and passing with no clinging or aversion hence not creating Fabrications / Formations / Sankara. This on its own right is wholesome hence this produces [Piti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%ABti) followed by [Passaddhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passaddhi) which is generally initially pleasant (Piti) and then more neutral (Passaddhi).